# Ckeditor 4 is loading too slow in our product, How to preload ckeditor4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor4.x

Can I preload ckeditor4? I did some research and tried some of the solutions available on google, but nothing helped. Is there any way to speedup ckeditor4 loading time? specifically when it loads for the first time.

Also, I tried to load ckeditor4 in a hidden div and textarea on window.onload. Replacing hidden div element or textarea didn't worked.

Thanks in advance :)

P.S - I already removed all unnecessary plug-ins and complied it from source.

Comment: Are you sure it's the run time and not the loading time of the files, that's the problem here? You should first make sure the loading of the files is as fast as possible. Are all the JS files compressed, preferably all into a single file? Is the webserver configured to use GZIP? BTW, `onload` is the worst place to place something that should happen fast, because it's literally the last thing that is executed.

Comment: Have you tried loading it from the [official CDN](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/)?